# Evolve in technical side as well as business side

Tags: traduction

How would we translate

> To evolve in both technical side as well as business side

and perhaps its variations

> To evolve in both technical competence and business knowledge
>
> To gain knowledge in both technical and functional domain
>
> To develop double competence in both domain technical-business

The idea is about evolving in two domains. Which one sounds better to you and sounds more French when translated ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please consider [visiting the Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and reformulate your question  so that you avoid asking for a translation, translations are off-topic.

Comment: "Évolution à la fois du côté/point de vue technique et du côté/point de vue business", "Évolution tant du point de vue technique que celui du business", "Aquisition de connaissance/savoir dans le domaine technique et fontionnel", "Développement d'une double compétence dans le domaine technique et du business/des affaires." Note that depending on what comes before "to ..." will change how the first word is to be translated ("Évolution/Pour évoluer/Évoluer/...). There are a lot more possible translations for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translations :

To evolve in both technical side as well as business side -
*Progresser aussi bien sur le plan technique que sur le plan des affaires/du business*

To evolve in both technical competence and business knowledge -
*Progresser dans les compétences techniques et la connaissance du business*

To gain knowledge in both technical and functional domain -
*Acquérir des connaissances à la fois dans le domaine technique et le domaine fonctionnel*

To develop double competence in both domain technical-business -
*Développer une double compétence technico-business*

The ones that sound better in french when translated are :

*Acquérir des connaissances à la fois dans le domaine technique et le domaine fonctionnel* -> Simple, effective, actually means something ("Progresser sur le plan technique etc.." is inaccurate)

*Développer une double compétence technico-business* -> More formal, efficient, complies with professionnal jargon.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a translation service, and expected answers are not supposed to be translations.  Please visit the [Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) and help us keep FL the place where we can ["discuss the finer points of the French language.](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour)". Plenty of translations services out there if OP wants a translation.

Comment: 1. "Proofreading or translation, unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified". There is a specific source of concern.
2. I also answered an interesting question at the end of my answer.
3. I want to help, i do not care pleasing you.
3. Who do you think you are ?

Cheers

Comment: Specific source of concern is **not** clearly specified in the question. There are plenty of interesting ways you could help French Language if you do want to help the site. Welcome to French Language!

Comment: @Laure:
1. If you have a look at the right side of the page, section _Related_, you'll see _How to we translate etc_ questions
http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13020/traduire-loose-cannon-franc-tireur-%C3%A9lectron-libre-ou-mieux-que-%C3%A7a?rq=1
http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12476/theres-no-such-thing-as-love-only-proof-of-love?rq=1
http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11911/can-you-somehow-translate-this?rq=1
2. Why would we have a tag _traduction_ then ? 
3. There is a point of _how to put correctly Evolve in 2 domains_ in the question.
4. Just my 5c :)

Comment: @Kenny What **French** word or expression (not English) are you having problems with? Your **which one** should refer to sentences in French not in English! You can modify your question and ask for it to be reopened, no problem, I'm sure you'll get interesting answers.

Comment: The entire expression as a whole. I know how to translate each and every word but i could not just stick them together because it would not make sense taking out of the context, isn't it ? Besides, aren't we contradicting ourselves and dotting the i's ? Another question of mine, asked in French as you prefer, was put on hold as well.
http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/mon-exp%C3%A9rience-professionnel-me-permet-de-bien-comprendre-des-processus-m%C3%A9tiers/19352#19352
If the answer get 4 votes, perhaps it did help someone learn something. Keep an open mind, as in the English SE.

Comment: @PénélopeDesSatré even if "[you] want to help, [you] do not care pleasing [us].", this is not the place for translations. This is a rule, this is a fact, if you do not want to obey it, it may mean this is not the place you are looking for. you may go somewhere else, where they provide translations.  Here the goal is to explain "why", not to give the result without explainations. A famous proverb says "Plutôt que de donner un poisson à un mendiant, apprends lui à pêcher". I think this is the actual goal of this rule.

Comment: @Kenny The other questions you link to suggest a French tentative translation and pinpoint the specific issue; one is related to literature. You have asked questions where you did suggest a French word and explained the difficulty. In this case your examples don't appear to be idiomatic English to boot. The context feels like the resume and it's about phrasing. Asking for what sounds better is just subjective, and you made no effort to show what you have so far. What should future readers be looking for in order to discover your content once it's no longer visible in the active queue? Thanks.