# Mon expérience professionnel me permet de bien comprendre des processus métiers

Tags: traduction, orthographe

Is it correct to say

> Mon expérience professionnel me permet de bien comprendre des
>   processus métiers et des besoins fonctionnels du monde d'entreprise

Any way I can improve the sentence ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with the boring stuff: you would say **"professionnelle"** to match the gender of "expérience".

Then I would probably replace **"des"** with **"les"** both times, to appear more decisive and precise.

Finally, I would replace "du monde d'entreprise" with **"du monde de l'entreprise"** (or simply "du monde professionnel").
Which gives us:

> Mon expérience professionnelle me permet de bien comprendre les
>   processus métiers et les besoins fonctionnels du monde de l'entreprise